# How to combine multiple IF statements in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I have some flawed logic here..my goal is if all of the fields have "" value then return true, otherwise return false. How can I fix this in C# ?

```
 public bool CheckFieldsAreEmpty()
        {
            Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(smtpHostInputField);
            if (smtpHostInputField.GetAttribute("value") == "")
                return true;
            Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(smtpPortInputField);
            if (smtpPortInputField.GetAttribute("value") == "")
                return true;
            Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(usernameInputField);
            if (usernameInputField.GetAttribute("value") == "")
                return true;
            Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(passwordInputField);
            if (passwordInputField.GetAttribute("value") == "")
                return true;
            Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(senderInputField);
            if (senderInputField.GetAttribute("value") == "")
                return true;
            Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(receiverInputField);
            if (receiverInputField.GetAttribute("value") == "")
                return true;

            else return false;
```

Comment: Invert the tests. If the first one is not empty, the whole condition fails so return false, and so on for each field. Return true if everything fails the not-empty test.

Comment: hmm, but what I'm looking for is an AND of some type, so if field #2 AND field #3 AND field #4 are value ="" then return true.

Comment: @hedda that's exactly what you're getting by waiting until all tests have completed without returning `false` - if you reach the end, 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 _must_ have all passed your test

Comment: FYI: I threw together @madreflection’s comment as an answer with a code example to help illustrate their suggestion. That should make it easier to reason through why it works. (Since I didn’t propose it, I marked it as a community wiki.) I also included a shorthand for centralizing the repetitive code while I was at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate @madreflection’s (correct) suggestion from the comments, consider this code:

```
public bool CheckFieldsAreEmpty()
{
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(smtpHostInputField);
    if (smtpHostInputField.GetAttribute("value") != "")
        return false;
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(smtpPortInputField);
    if (smtpPortInputField.GetAttribute("value") != "")
        return false;
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(usernameInputField);
    if (usernameInputField.GetAttribute("value") != "")
        return false;
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(passwordInputField);
    if (passwordInputField.GetAttribute("value") != "")
        return false;
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(senderInputField);
    if (senderInputField.GetAttribute("value") != "")
        return false;
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(receiverInputField);
    if (receiverInputField.GetAttribute("value") != "")
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Of course, as [@Daniel-Lord’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67025996/3025856) highlights, you can centralize this repetitive logic using either a loop or a LINQ query.

Answer (score 3):

I believe something like this should work.  I couldn't find what class all of those variables belong to, but replace var with the proper class and I think this should work.

logic:  Add all variables to a List, use a lambda function to return if all of the list match GetAttribute("value") == ""

```
// Replace var with class type, or parent
List<var> allFields = new List<var> { smtpHostInputField, smtpPortInputField, sernameInputField, passwordInputField, senderInputField, receiverInputField };

foreach (var field in allFields) { Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(field); }

return allFields.All(t => t.GetAttribute("value") == "");
```

Comment: It would be `All`, not `Any`. OP wants true if they're all empty.

Comment: @madreflection good point OP stated it the way you described, and then wrote pseudo code for Any.  Not sure which one OP is looking for.

Comment: It's clearly stated at the top: *"my goal is if all of the fields have "" value then return true"*

Comment: And before that, *"I have some flawed logic here"*, so clearly the code is not a reliable indication of what they want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this would be to extract `WaitForElementValueNull` call and empty string check to a separate method. Something like that:

```
private static bool WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(InputFieldType inputField)
{
    Driver.WaitForElementValueNull(inputField);
    return inputField.GetAttribute("value") == "";
}
     
public bool CheckFieldsAreEmpty()
{
    return WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(smtpHostInputField) ||
           WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(smtpPortInputField) ||
           WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(usernameInputField) ||
           WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(passwordInputField) ||
           WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(senderInputField) ||
           WaitForElementValueNullAndEmpty(receiverInputField);
}
```

The code above will match the algorithm that was provided, however if you want to check if ALL the values is empty then `||` should be replaced with `&&` (As it was noticed by Jeremy Caney)

Comment: Those should be `&&` since the problem the OP is trying to solve is determining if _all_ values are empty.

Comment: I'm trying this solution but can't quite figure out what InputFieldType should be ?